# Selecting rows from table starting from a specific row

Tags: mysql, sql

In a single page blog is there a simple way to select posts starting from a specific post using mysql.

I don't suggest using `LIMIT 40,20` (**edit:** in case of `ORDER BY modified_date DESC`) because it would return posts starting from 40 and creating posts before the user requests the next page would make him see the same post twice. also deleting a post would make him miss a post.

so I'd like to make the page requests the next post's id that should appear and the server replies with some posts after it.

So can i find a mysql statement that selects the posts starting form id=X?

it should be like this or any other thing that does the job

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY modified DESC LIMIT 20 [STARTING_FROM id=40]
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

you can use it in where condition . Like this

```
    SELECT * FROM posts where id >= 40 ORDER BY modified LIMIT 20
```

Comment: That's a very intelligent answer, in case of (id is auto incremented and retrieved posts are ordered by id or any thing with the same order such as created time),
can you give a more general solution, please look at the updated question.

Comment: i tried hard to understand you but i couldnt , anyway i edited my answer and if you wanna filter more data , you can just add `AND` clause after `WHERE` like `AND created_date < some_date` or whatever you want . or you can post some data and wished results so i can look to it and understand it .

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE STARTING_FROM_id >= 40 LIMIT 20;
```